# Compare Dates from arrays of different objects in aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

on my project i have users that complete combinations (called sessions) of courses. the fact of playing a course is called an attempt. During the attempt they can close it and come back later (so we keep a timelog object).

I have a request from the client which needs to return for each session, the users (and their attempts) that have played whole or part of their session during a certain timeframe.

During a certain timeframe means that the client sends a begin and end date and we count a user for a specific session if:
 - the first attempt has begun before the end of the timeframe => the started of the first timelog of the first < ending date
- the last attempt has been finished after the begining of the timeframe => the end of the last timelog of the last attempt > starting date

Here is an example of an attempt object (the only one we need to use here):

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b9148650ab5f43b5e829a4b"),
"index" : 0,
"author" : ObjectId("5acde2646055980a84914b6b"),
"timelog" : [
    {
        "started" : ISODate("2018-09-06T15:31:49.163Z"),
        "ended" : ISODate("2018-09-06T15:32:03.935Z")
    },
    ...
],
"session" : ObjectId("5b911d31e58dc13ab7586f9b")}
```

- My idea was to make an aggregate on the attempts, to group those using `author` and `session` as an `_id` for the `$group` stage, and to push all the attempts of the user for this particular session into an array `userAttempts`.
- Then to make an $addField stage to retrieve the started field of the first timelog of the first attempt and the last ended of the last attempt.
- And finally to $filter or $match using those new fields.

Here is my aggregate:

```
const newDate = new Date()
_db.attempts.aggregate([
        { $match: {
            author: { $in: programSessionsData.users },
            $or: [{ programSession: { $in: programSessionIds } }, { oldTryFor: { $in: programSessionIds } }],
            globalTime: $ex,
            timelog: $ex }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    user: "$author",
                    programSession: "$programSession"
                },
                userAttempts: { $push: { attemptId: "$_id", lastTimelog: { $arrayElemAt: ["$timelog", -1] }, timelog: "$timelog" } }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields: { begin: { $reduce: {
                input: "$userAttempts",
                initialValue: newDate,
                in: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $lt: ["$$this.timelog.0.started", "$$value"] },
                        then: "$$this.timelog.0.started",
                        else: "$$value"
                    } }
            } } }
        }
```

I also tried this for the addFields stage:

```
{
            $addFields: { begin: { $reduce: {
                input: "$userAttempts",
                initialValue: newDate,
                in: { $min: ["$$this.timelog.0.started", "$$value] }
            } } }
}
```

**However everytime begin is an empty array.** 
I do not really know how i can extract those two date, or compare dates between them.

**To Note**: the end one is more difficult that is why i have to first extract lastTimelog. If you an other method i would gladly take it.

Also this code is on a node server so i cannot use ISODate. and the mongo version used is 3.6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with aggregate a bit i came up with 2 solutions:

Solution 1

```
_db.attempts.aggregate([
        { $match: {
            query
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    user: "$author",
                    programSession: "$programSession"
                },
                userAttempts: { $push: { attemptId: "$_id", timelog: "$timelog" } }
            }
        }, {
            $addFields: {
                begin: { $reduce: {
                    input: "$userAttempts",
                    initialValue: newDate,
                    in: { $min: [{ $reduce: {
                        input: "$$this.timelog",
                        initialValue: newDate,
                        in: { $min: ["$$this.started", "$$value"] }
                    } }, "$$value"] }
                } },
                end: { $reduce: {
                    input: "$userAttempts",
                    initialValue: oldDate,
                    in: { $max: [{ $reduce: {
                        input: "$$this.timelog",
                        initialValue: oldDate,
                        in: { $max: ["$$this.ended", "$$value"] }
                    } }, "$$value"] }
                } }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                begin: { $lt: req.body.ended },
                end: { $gt: req.body.started }
            }
        }
    ], { allowDiskUse: true });
```

newDate is today and oldDate is an arbitrary date in the past.
I had to chain 2 reduce because "$$this.timelog.0.started" would always return nothing. Don't really know why though.

Solution 2

```
_db.attempts.aggregate([
        { $match: {
           query
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                firstTimelog: { $arrayElemAt: ["$timelog", 0] },
                lastTimelog: { $arrayElemAt: ["$timelog", -1] }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    user: "$author",
                    programSession: "$programSession"
                },
                begin: { $min: "$firstTimelog.started" },
                end: { $max: "$lastTimelog.ended" },
                userAttempts: { $push: { attemptId: "$_id", timelog: "$timelog"} }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                begin: { $lt: req.body.ended },
                end: { $gt: req.body.started }
            }
        }
    ], { allowDiskUse: true });
```

This one is a lot more straight forward and seems simpler, but oddly enough, from my testing, Solution 1 is always quicker at least in the object distribution for my project.